# Is there a way to use IsMouseOver in a resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

When I use the below block of code in a Window or control it works (I can see the button animation and the size of the button changes when I hover over it), but it does not work when I use it in the resource dictionary. I am creating a Prism app with mah apps window.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
                    xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
                    xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                    xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                    
                   >
    <!--// Merge Dic here //-->
    <ContentControl x:Key="OperatorUIPreview" 
                    Content="{StaticResource splashStyle}"/>

    <ContentControl x:Key="OperatorUI.Home" 
                  Background="Purple">

        <Grid >
            <Border 
                        Background="#323345"
                        CornerRadius="10,10,0,0"
                        Margin="0,85,0,0">

                <Grid >
                    <Button
                                x:Name="home1"
                                Background="Blue"
                         
                            Style="{StaticResource DockBtnStyle}">

                        <Popup Width="70"
                                   HorizontalOffset="-12"
                                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=home1}"
                                   IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=home1, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PopupStyle}">

                            <Grid>
                                <Border Style="{StaticResource border}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Home"
                                                   Style="{StaticResource PopupText}" />
                                </Border>

                                <Path Style="{StaticResource ArrowPath}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Style:

```
  <Style x:Key="DockBtnStyle"
        TargetType="Button">

        <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="50" />

        <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="50" />

        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                    <Border x:Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />

                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>

        <!--// Button Animation //-->

        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Width)"
                                        To="65"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.3" />

                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Height)"
                                        To="65"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Width)"
                                        To="50"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.3" />

                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Height)"
                                        To="50"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: That popup looks like it could instead be a tooltip.  Where's the content of that contentcontrol?

Comment: @Andy Isn't the Grid and everything inside considered the content?(First time using contentcontrols) - The button Appears but the mouseover effect is not happening

Comment: A contentcontol let's you put some other non fixed content inside it.  You may as well have a usercontrol here. And again, a thing that appears when you mouse over something is a tooltip.

Comment: @Andy I have added the style to show the mouse-over I was referring to

Comment: Don't put a control in a resource dictionary. You can only use a control in one place in the UI.  So what's it doing in a resource dictionary?  Still makes no sense that this is a content control.

Comment: How are you using the resource called "OperatorUI.Home"? I've copied the above xaml into a test project then in the page's XAML I've added a ContentPresenter with `Content="{StaticResource OperatorUI.Home}"` and that seems to work for me.

Comment: @Dev: What doesn't work exactly? Is the style even applied to the `Button`? How do you use the `ContentControl` in a view?